# How to get content-encoding from ApiGateway caching resource

Tags: node.js, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless

We have an endpoint that returns a gzip encoding. We want to cache the value and we are using ApiGateway to do that for us. The resource method is defined as follows,

```
GetManifestApiGatewayMethod: # very good
      Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
      Properties:
        AuthorizationType: "NONE"
        HttpMethod: "GET"
        ResourceId:
          Ref: ManifestConfigurationResource
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
        RequestParameters:
          method.request.path.seasonCode: true
          method.request.path.facilityCode: true
          method.request.path.configurationCode: true
          method.request.querystring.policyCode: true
          method.request.header.PAC-Authorization: true
          method.request.header.PAC-Application-ID: true
          method.request.header.PAC-API-Key: true
          method.request.header.PAC-Channel-Code: true
          method.request.header.PAC-Organization-ID: true
          method.request.header.PAC-Developer-ID: true
          method.request.header.PAC-Request-ID: false
          method.request.header.Accept-Encoding: true
        MethodResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
            # ResponseParameters:
            #   method.response.header.Content-Encoding: true
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
          Type: HTTP
          Uri: https://${self:provider.environment.PDI_HOST}/pdi/v1/manifest/{seasonCode}/{facilityCode}/{configurationCode}
          PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
          CacheKeyParameters:
            - method.request.path.seasonCode
            - method.request.path.facilityCode
            - method.request.path.configurationCode
            - method.request.querystring.policyCode
          IntegrationResponses:
            - StatusCode: 200
              SelectionPattern: '\d\d\d'
              # ResponseParameters:
              #   method.response.header.content-encoding: integration.response.body.headers.content-encoding
          RequestParameters:
            integration.request.path.seasonCode: method.request.path.seasonCode
            integration.request.path.facilityCode: method.request.path.facilityCode
            integration.request.path.configurationCode: method.request.path.configurationCode
            integration.request.querystring.policyCode: method.request.querystring.policyCode
            integration.request.header.Authorization: method.request.header.PAC-Authorization
            integration.request.header.PAC-Application-ID: method.request.header.PAC-Application-ID
            integration.request.header.PAC-API-Key: method.request.header.PAC-API-Key
            integration.request.header.PAC-Channel-Code: method.request.header.PAC-Channel-Code
            integration.request.header.PAC-Organization-ID: method.request.header.PAC-Organization-ID
            integration.request.header.PAC-Developer-ID: method.request.header.PAC-Developer-ID
            integration.request.header.PAC-Request-ID: method.request.header.PAC-Request-ID
            integration.request.header.Accept-Encoding: method.request.header.Accept-Encoding
```

http.get method has the following logic in it:

`const encoding = response.headers["content-encoding"];
if (encoding && encoding.indexOf("gzip") >= 0) {...} // handle the gzip`

but when we use the integration method above, I am not getting that header that I would normally get from directly hitting the api it proxies to. There is some commented code where I tried to pass that along but Im getting `internal server error` when those response mappings are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of your code template, the Method response header looks correct.

```
method.response.header.Content-Encoding: true
```

However your integration response, ResponseParameters is seems wrong.

```
method.response.header.content-encoding: integration.response.body.headers.content-encoding
```

Firstly, the property **Key** should exactly match, so potentially the capitalisation may be adding to the issue. However, your **Value** looks to be the real issue. As per the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration-integrationresponse.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-integrationresponse-responseparameters):

> Use the destination as the key and the source as the value:
>
> The destination must be an existing response parameter in the
> MethodResponse property.
>
> The source must be an existing method request parameter or a static
> value. You must enclose static values in single quotation marks and
> pre-encode these values based on the destination specified in the
> request.

It looks as if you're trying to map a integration response method to the value instead of a **Method Request parameter**.

Comment: changing the integration response parameters as follows fails cloudformation `method.response.header.Content-Encoding: 'gzip'`

Comment: This did the trick. Im still lost on how can let it pass the value instead of statically declaring it. `method.response.header.Content-Encoding: "'gzip'"`

Comment: To pass the value dynamically, you will need to either create a mapping template logic or return the value from the service endpoint or have the initial call include the correct value in the request.

Comment: can you help me create a mapping template? @pkarfs